# Extending component props to default html button props correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a button component that has `variant` prop to determine it's color. Here is simplified version

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}

function Button({ variant, ...props }: Props) {
  console.log(variant);

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

I am getting typescript error under my `type` that says:

> (JSX attribute) ButtonHTMLAttributes.type?:
>   "button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined Type 'string' is not
>   assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset" |
>   undefined'.ts(2322) index.d.ts(1872, 9): The expected type comes from
>   property 'type' which is declared here on type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLButtonElement>'

So I am not sure if I am extending to button props correctly? Perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update 2023**

if you want to create button without any extra stuff you can extend `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">` and for people that trying to make reusable component you will need to `forwardRef` the underlying element  and then you can use `ComponentPropsWithRef`:

```
interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button"> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}
```

why not using `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`?

this is what happens when you use:

```
export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  /* etc */
}

function App() {
  // Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'
  return <Button type="submit"> text </Button>;
}
```

**Old answers**

[Codesandbox Live Preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bouman-bzxik?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

what you're probably looking for is `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}

function Button({ variant, ...props }: Props) {

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Button variant='green' />, rootElement);
```

to being more accurate we can use `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

interface Props extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}

function Button({ variant, ...props }: Props) {

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Button variant="green" />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I'd recommend being more specific, e.g. `... extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Comment: **2023**: The answer probably needs to be updated, I can't find `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<>` it just doesn't exist in the `React` namespace and I can't find any answers in React's documentation.

Answer (score 10):

You should use `ButtonHTMLAttributes` rather than `HTMLProps` like this:

```
interface Props extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}

function Button({ variant, ...props }: Props) {
  console.log(variant);

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution to this same problem, you can replace `'button'` for any html tag

```
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

interface ButtonProps extends ComponentProps<'button'> {
  variant: 'yellow' | 'green';
}

function Button({ variant, ...props }: ButtonProps) {
```